# Angular npm build not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am new to angular and npm. 
I am trying to add kama and jasmine, so I come to the stage to npm run build, but I cannot pass that step.

here is my package.json

---

```
{
  "name": "angular2-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run gulp\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.5",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.4.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^5.0.13",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.3",
    "precss": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Could someone help me on that ! many thanks!

and here is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.11.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.6
3 info using node@v5.11.0
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:147:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:57:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:345:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:309:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:343:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:113:5)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:232:12
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
4 verbose stack     at tryToString (fs.js:414:3)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:401:12)
5 verbose cwd 
6 error Darwin 15.6.0
7 error argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.11.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
8 error node v5.11.0
9 error npm  v3.8.6
10 error missing script: build
11 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
11 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: add ``"build"`` inside ``"scripts": {}``

Comment: or u edit the ``"start"`` value...

Answer (score 0):

To run your application just run the below command from command prompt:

```
  npm start
```